# How to calculate the spring force of a rolled piece of steel?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, springs, material-science, elastic-modulus, deformation

If you have a steel sheet and then curled it to the point of being a semi-circle with a `30 degree` (`pi/6`) gap from completion (see photo for a better representation) and a radius of 3 inches, that steel sheet would then act as a weak spring when pushed or pulled. If you then put the curled steel sheet in a vertical pipe with a diameter slightly smaller than the curled steel sheet's diameter, the expansion forces would push against the walls of the pipe and keep it in place. Let's say the pipe expands back until a `15 degree` (`pi/12`) gap in the circle is present. How large could the pipe be before the curled sheet fell?

[image: Forces in ring]

This is straightforward, is the friction force equal to the weight: `Ff = mg`; F = Expansion force, f = coefficient of friction, m = mass, g = gravity

If the tube is concrete then the friction coefficient between the tube and the sheet would be `0.57` (as found [here](https://ascelibrary.org/doi/10.1061/%28ASCE%290733-9445%281985%29111%3A3%28505%29)). Which leaves finding a reaction force. I start by looking at Hooks law:
`F = -k(x)`; F = force, k = the spring constant; x = displacement

I need to find the spring constant and displacement. k can be found with Youngs modulus: `k = E(a/L)`; E = Youngs modulus, a = area, L = length

However, I am unsure how to quantify displacement since the displacement is in the x and y axis, not just one or the other like the equation wants. I thought using the circle radius that enclosed the rolled sheet would eliminate one axis since it is the same everywhere. So I used that; radius goes from `3in` to `2.87` when compressed in the pipe.

I use circumference as the length, so the force should be:

`F = -E(a/L)(x) = -28000ksi * (0.264 in^2)/(17.279 in) * 0.13 in = 55614.33 lbf`

Not only does this seem much too large of a number, but I am also not confident in my process. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Hey, this is a case of bending an already curved item! Spring constant is useless here because there's no single direction force. You should calculate which surface pressure distribution makes your pipe to have the right size to fit into the outer pipe and then calculate the net friction force.

Comment: @user287001 thanks for the insight and direction. The spring constant being useless tracks with why I couldn't make an equation work (hah).